# Init field after constructor execution

Tags: java, oop, parameter-passing

Suppose a Car Validator and many methods that read its attributes to valid them.
Thus, the best way to structure it is to make Car an instance field.

Two ways of making it :

**1)** make a constructor taking a Car as argument and then call validate().

**2)** Remove all constructors but rather pass Car to validate method as arguments: validate(Car car).

If we imagine that this validator must continuously validate, let's say 500 cars.

With the **1)** method, 500 validator objects must be instanciated ... Even if Garbage collector is doing its job really well, it doesn't seem to be the best practice.
The benefit is that initialization of Car field is made by constructor => so more natural way.

With the **2)** method, we avoid the drawback of the **1)** but we have to init Car field into the method validate, that means after object construction. Is that considered as a good practice? Indeed, only validate method use Car field and furthermore, there is only validate method that is not private.

Of course, there is a third way to do this for avoiding all doubts => pass Car from validate method toward each private methods...but I find this very ugly...

Which of the three methods should I choose ?

Comment: Why you want to validate Car at server side ? Isn't it possible to validate it @ client side and then proceed ?

Comment: It's a conceptual sample. I could use this concept to valid a JPA entity for example or other things at server side.

Comment: I am not getting why you want to validate entity after instantiation If Car properties are supplied at a time of creation of its object, then i think no need to validate them and/or if supplied by end user, then validating at client side may help you.

Comment: If we follow SRP and if desired validation process is very more complex than simple 'checkForNull', validation should be separate from Car behaviour (in other word Car entity).

Comment: I do like this question (+1), though I think it could be explained less ambiguously by always clarifying which class you are talking about when mentioning constructor/method.

Comment: Yes, next questions (if any ^^) I will show sample code, you're right for context understanding it's better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 2nd approach is an antipattern and should be avoided, it resembles the infamous `SimpleDateFormat` class (it looks like stateless and thread safe, but it's not).

Regarding the other approaches, if you really have many private methods it would be better to use the 1st approach, otherwise you can use the 3rd approach, it doesn't look too ugly for me.

Also note that using the 1st approach "as is" involves more coupling than the 3rd one. In the 3rd case you can decouple clients of validator from its implementation by injecting a preconfigured instance of validator, whereas in the 1st case you need to introduce a factory to achieve the same effect.

Comment: How is the 2nd approach the "SimpleDateFormat-antipattern"?

Comment: @DaveBall: In the 1st case we clearly see that we should validate each `Car` with its own instance of validator. In the 3rd case we can validate multiple `Car`s with a single validator without restrictions. In the 2nd case we can validate multiple `Car`s with a single validator, but not simultaneously. That's a hidden restriction, exactly as in `SimpleDataFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

**Good practice is typically that which avoids drawbacks.**

Use the second method.  If you're going to create a `CarValidator` class and call `validate(car)` on it to check validity on your objects, that seems a very efficient way to do it.  I don't understand why you would think that it wouldn't be best practice?

Are you concerned about setting a private `Car` variable and referring to it throughout the validation process rather than passing an instance around through all the private methods?  As long as the `validate` method is synchronized, this approach wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I really enjoy your two advices (@axtavt and you). I agree with you as soon as we are in a non-multithreaded environment, as you say it :) So, I would choose the third approach. Less elegeant but without significative drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a fourth approach and check validity of cars as early as possible by **injecting a Validator object into the Car constructors**. I find that a far smaller drawback than having invalid car instances hanging around and having to check validity (via validity() or via attribute in Validator object) later (i.e. not fail fast) at multiple places.

---

Update: If you cannot validate Car instances during their construction, e.g. because you're on the client side, I would consider Car instances as tainted values on your server side and use [the tainting checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checkers-manual.html#tainting-checker) and your method 2 to untaint them.

Comment: I agree but I didn't specify all my context. My construction Car is actually made using the Essence pattern. (equivalent to the builder of Joshua Bloch). So no Car is created without being validated before.

Comment: You mean Effective Java item 2? That's quite elegant :) So you need to validate cars under different aspects - or why would you want to "revalidate" afterwards?

Comment: As I said above, I want to follow Single Responsibility principle so I made a specific class called CarValidator (for sample). This validator is called by each car being created (but not totally since not validated yet :)) If this validator allow one car to exist, this one could be returned to client, otherwize an exception is thrown like a IllegalArgumentException or even IllegalStateException. So 500 different cars would call this unique instance of validator (thread-safe) so that Garbage collector can rest in peace :)  Indeed, Effective Java talked about that kind of builder.

Comment: @Mik378, I'm beginning to understand ;) Are you calling validate on the parameters given to your builder, or are you calling `validate(this);` or `Validator v = new Validator(this); v.validate();` at the end of your Car constructor? I would only do the latter two cases if Car were final...

Comment: The problem with constructor concept is that they have to allow all permutation possibilities. Short sample : for a Person entity, name and age are compulsory but not childrenList. So if we keep closed to the constructor concept, it would have a Person(name, age) Person (name, age, children)... very redondant. The concept with Builder pattern is to set ALL needed fields to a PersonBuilder (nested class) and so validation is called into it, when caller invoke : Person p = builder.newInstance();  Thus, no need final keyword for attributes because no Person exists BEFORE validation.

Comment: Thus, all permutations are possible since Builder is an object itself containing the different setters to build a Person. So Person class itself only contains getter since Person should be immutable when creating (indeed, difficult to change his age...) Ok for childrenList but...this was just a simple sample ;)  To sum up my call to Validator is made within the static inner class called PersonBuilder :    new PersonValidator(this)   (this pointing to Builder instance and not Person itself)   For more informations, it's very well explained here : http://www.xavena.eu/immutable-objects/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how the "Josh Bloch's builder pattern" works. I was wondering how the validation is called when builder.newInstance() is invoked: I listed the variants I could think of in my previous post and concluded that in the latter two cases, the **class Car** should be final. Otherwise, the Car subclass SportsCar would call `validate` before the SportsCar specific setup of the newly created instance has been completed...

Comment: If we use constructor, then obviously Car class should be final since as you know parent's constructor is called before child's one. However, if you use Builder and not constructor to call your validate method, nothing prevents you to not mark them as final. Logic will say that it doesn't make much sense (indeed, why all this structure for validation if a simple subclass could "burst" the whole ?)